# List index out of range Python tweet manager, tweets not saving?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I'm trying to make a Tweet Manager for a class project and am having some issues with the "View tweets" function. I also don't think my tweets are saving (they are supposed to be serialized and saved to be accessible at later times). I keep getting the IndexError "list index out of range" but I definitely made 5 tweets?

Here is my code:

```
import Tweet, pickle

timeline = []

save_tweets = 'tweets.dat'

def main():    
    while True:
        tweet_menu()

        choice = get_choice()
        if choice==1:
            make_tweet()
        elif choice==2:
            view_tweets()
        elif choice==3:
            search_tweets()
        elif choice==4:
            print('Thank you for using Tweet Manager.')
           break

def tweet_menu():
    print(' ')
    print('Tweet Menu')
    print('_____________')
    print('1. Make a tweet')
    print('2. View recent tweets')
    print('3. Search tweets')
    print('4. Quit')

def get_choice():
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input('Which would you like to do? '))
            if choice < 1 or choice > 4:
                print('That is not a valid choice.')
                continue
        except:
            print('Please enter a number between 1 and 4.')
        else:
            break

    return choice

def make_tweet():
        author = input('What is your name? ')
        while True:
            text = input('What would you like to tweet? ')
            if len(text) > 140:
                print('Error: Tweets cannot be longer than 140 characters.')
                continue
            else:
                break
        age = 0               

        #Create a tweet object.
        tweet = Tweet.Tweet(author,text,age)

        #Add the tweet to the list.
        timeline.append(tweet)

        #Encrypt the tweets to a data file.
        try:
            save_tweets = open('tweets.dat', 'wb')
            pickle.dump(timeline, save_tweets)
            save_tweets.close()
        except:
            print('Your tweets could not be saved.')

        print('Your tweet has been saved.')


def view_tweets():

    #Unpickle the tweets so the user can access them.
    try:
        load_file = open(save_tweets, 'rb')
        timeline = pickle.load(load_file)
        load_file.close()

     except:
         print('The tweets could not be loaded.')

    print('Recent Tweets')
    print('______________')
    if len(timeline) == 0:
         print('There are no recent tweets.')
    for tweet in timeline[-5]:
        print(timeline.get_author, '-', timeline.get_age)
        print(timeline.get_text)


def search_tweets():
    match = 0
    timeline.reverse()

    if timeline ==[]:
        print('There are no tweets to search at this time.')

    search = input('What would you like to search for? ')
    for tweet in timeline:
        if (search in timeline.get_text):
            match = 1
        if match == 1:
            print('Search Results')
            print('_______________')
            print(tweet.Tweet.get_author, '-', tweet.Tweet.get_age)
            print(tweet.Tweet.get_text)
        else:
            print('Search Results')
            print('_______________')
            print('No tweets contained ', tweet.Tweet.get_author, 
            tweet.Tweet.get_text)

main()
```

Comment: Where/when are you getting list index out of range?

Comment: Also, you are aware that pickle doesn't do any encrypting, right?

Comment: I was not aware, I guess I misinterpreted my book. I'm in an intro class and this is my first time programming. I am getting list index out of range in the fuction "view_tweets()"  in "for tweet in timeline[-5]". I  am supposed to call up the 5 most recent tweets.

Comment: my mistake, I am not supposed to encrypt, just serialize and save to an external file.

Comment: You generally can't just use a negative number in an array index - what are you trying to accomplish there?